Problemas con post requests para la plataforma Bybit.com
¡Hola!
Este es un proyecto interesante que me gustaría compartir en GitHub, estoy haciendo una librería para peticiones api dedicada a Bybit.com, pero no logro realizar las peticiones POST correctamente, no entiendo muy bien como construir el encabezado post, si alguien sabe hacerlo seria genial que lo compartiera. Tengo especial problema con la construcción de la firma.
({"retCode":10004,"retMsg":"Signature for this request is not valid.","result":{},"retExtInfo":{},"time":1714610299398}).
No tengo mucha experiencia realizando solicitudes API y me encuentro abrumado.
El link de la documentación oficial es este: https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v3/intro#parameters-for-authenticated-endpoints
El código esta escrito en el lenguaje de programación C++-
La petición la hago de la siguiente manera:
const std::string base = "/v5/order/create";

WebRequest req;

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> parameters = {
{"category", "spot"},
{"orderType", "Market"},
{"symbol", symbols[c].first},
{"side", "Buy"},
{"orderType", "Market"},
{"qty", quote}
};

req.sendSignedRequest("POST", base, parameters);

if (req.json["retCode"] == 0) {
std::cout << "Compra exitosa!" << std::endl;
}

#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <json/json.h>

#include "../src/debug.cpp"

extern const std::string apiKey;
extern const std::string apiSecret;

#define baseUrl "https://api.bybit.com"

#define GET_TIMESTAMP() \
([=]() -> std::string { \
    long long ms_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count(); \
    return std::to_string(ms_since_epoch); \
})()

#define ENCRYPT_WITH_HMAC(strKey, strData) \
([=](const std::string& strKey, const std::string& strData)-> std::string { \
    const char* key = strKey.c_str(); \
    const char* data = strData.c_str(); \
    unsigned char *result; \
    static char res_hex[64]; \
    int result_len = 32; \
    std::string signature; \
    \
    result = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, strlen((char *)key), const_cast<unsigned char *>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data)), strlen((char *)data), NULL, NULL); \
    for (int i = 0; i < result_len; i++) { \
        sprintf(&(res_hex[i * 2]), "%02x", result[i]); \
    } \
    \
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) { \
        signature += res_hex[i]; \
    } \
    \
    return signature; \
})(strKey, strData)

/* concatenate the query parameters to &<key>=<value> */
#define JOIN_QUERY_PARAMETERS(parameters) \
([](const std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> &parameters)->std::string { \
    std::string queryString = ""; \
    for (auto it = parameters.cbegin(); it != parameters.cend(); ++it) { \
            if (it == parameters.cbegin()) { \
                queryString += it->first + '=' + it->second; \
            } \
            \
            else { \
                queryString += '&' + it->first + '=' + it->second; \
            } \
    } \
    return queryString; \
})(parameters)

class WebRequest {
    
    public:
    Json::Value json;

    private:
    Json::Reader reader;
    std::string response;

    private:

    struct MemoryStruct {
        std::string memory;
        size_t size;
    };

    static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
        size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
        struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

        mem->memory.append((char *)contents, realsize);
        mem->size += realsize;

        return realsize;
    }

    void parseJson () {
        if (!reader.parse(response, json)) {
            std::cout << "Error parsing HTTP json response from bybit" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::string sendPrivateHTTPRequest(const std::string& url, const std::string& httpMethod, const std::string& queryString) {
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res = CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION;
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ("X-BAPI-API-KEY:" + apiKey).c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ("X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP:" + GET_TIMESTAMP()).c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ("X-BAPI-SIGN:" + ENCRYPT_WITH_HMAC(apiSecret, queryString)).c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW: 5000");
        MemoryStruct chunk = {"", 0};

        while (res != CURLE_OK){
            curl = curl_easy_init();
            if (curl) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &chunk);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

                if (httpMethod == "POST") {
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, queryString.c_str());
                } else if (httpMethod == "DELETE") {
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, queryString.c_str());
                }

                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                if (res != CURLE_OK) {
                    chunk = {"", 0};
                }
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            }
        }

        curl_slist_free_all(headers);
        headers = NULL; 
        std::cout << chunk.memory << std::endl;
        return chunk.memory;
    }

    public:
    void sendSignedRequest(std::string httpMethod, std::string urlPath, std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> &parameters) {
        std::string url = baseUrl + urlPath;
        std::string queryString = "";

        parameters.insert({
            {"api_key", apiKey},
            {"timestamp", GET_TIMESTAMP()},
        });

        if (!parameters.empty()) {
            queryString = JOIN_QUERY_PARAMETERS(parameters);
        }

        if (httpMethod == "GET") {
            std::string signature = "&sign=" + ENCRYPT_WITH_HMAC(apiSecret, queryString);
            queryString += signature;
        }

        response = sendPrivateHTTPRequest(url, httpMethod, queryString);

        parseJson();
    }
};


Yo creo que ver el código solamente no va a ayudar mucho. Puedes mostrar la información que se le envía al endpoint? queryString supongo que tendrá esa información. Por cierto, no encuentro información sobre ese endpoint

El query es el siguiente: side=Buy&qty=0.0002&symbol=BTCUSDT&orderType=Market&category=spot&timestamp=1714613165321

Siendo que es un POST. No debería enviar información en JSON?

encontré esto en esta pagina `# rule:
timestamp+api_key+recv_window+raw_request_body
param_str
1658385579423XXXXXXXXXX5000{
"category": "linear"
}
parse
timestamp = 1658385579423
api_key = XXXXXXXXXX
recv_window = 5000
raw_request_body = {"category": "linear"}` ahi esta el formato, cuando llegue a casa lo revisare... En cuanto a la respuesta, si, debiese estar en formato json.

necesito ayuda soy muy malo en esto

ya lo corregí, aun no estoy seguro de si funciona para todo, después publicare la respuesta

Al fin y al cabo logre resolver mis dudas relacionadas con las peticiones POST...
Aqui les dejo el fragmento de codigo corregido:
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <json/json.h>

#include "../src/debug.cpp"

extern const std::string apiKey;
extern const std::string apiSecret;

#define baseUrl "https://api.bybit.com"

#define GET_TIMESTAMP() \
([=]() -> std::string { \
    long long ms_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count(); \
    return std::to_string(ms_since_epoch); \
})()

#define ENCRYPT_WITH_HMAC(strKey, strData) \
([=](const std::string& strKey, const std::string& strData)-> std::string { \
    const char* key = strKey.c_str(); \
    const char* data = strData.c_str(); \
    unsigned char *result; \
    static char res_hex[64]; \
    int result_len = 32; \
    std::string signature; \
    \
    result = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, strlen((char *)key), const_cast<unsigned char *>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data)), strlen((char *)data), NULL, NULL); \
    for (int i = 0; i < result_len; i++) { \
        sprintf(&(res_hex[i * 2]), "%02x", result[i]); \
    } \
    \
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) { \
        signature += res_hex[i]; \
    } \
    \
    return signature; \
})(strKey, strData)

/* concatenate the query parameters to &<key>=<value> */
#define URL_QUERY(parameters) \
([](const std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> &parameters)->std::string { \
    std::string queryString = ""; \
    for (auto it = parameters.cbegin(); it != parameters.cend(); ++it) { \
            if (it == parameters.cbegin()) { \
                queryString += it->first + '=' + it->second; \
            } \
            \
            else { \
                queryString += '&' + it->first + '=' + it->second; \
            } \
    } \
    return queryString; \
})(parameters)

#define JSON_QUERY(parameters) \
([](const std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> &parameters)->std::string { \
    Json::Value root; \
    for (auto it = parameters.cbegin(); it != parameters.cend(); ++it) { \
        root[it->first] = it->second; \
    } \
    Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder; \
    builder["indentation"] = ""; \
    std::ostringstream os; \
    std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter()); \
    writer->write(root, &os); \
    return os.str(); \
})(parameters)


class WebRequest {
    
    public:
    Json::Value json;

    private:
    Json::Reader reader;
    std::string response;

    private:

    struct MemoryStruct {
        std::string memory;
        size_t size;
    };

    static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
        size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
        struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

        mem->memory.append((char *)contents, realsize);
        mem->size += realsize;

        return realsize;
    }

    void parseJson () {
        if (!reader.parse(response, json)) {
            std::cout << "Error parsing HTTP json response from bybit" << std::endl;
            std::cout << response << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::string sendPrivateHTTPRequest(const std::string& url, const std::string& httpMethod, const std::string& queryString) {
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res = CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION;
        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        std::string base = baseUrl;
        
        const std::string timestamp = GET_TIMESTAMP();
        const std::string sign = timestamp + apiKey + "5000" + queryString;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ("X-BAPI-SIGN: " + ENCRYPT_WITH_HMAC(apiSecret, sign)).c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ("X-BAPI-API-KEY: " + apiKey).c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ("X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP: " + timestamp).c_str());
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW: 5000");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

        MemoryStruct chunk = {"", 0};

        while (res != CURLE_OK){
            curl = curl_easy_init();
            if (curl) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &chunk);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

                if (httpMethod == "POST") {
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, queryString.c_str());
                } else if (httpMethod == "DELETE") {
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, queryString.c_str());
                }

                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                if (res != CURLE_OK) {
                    chunk = {"", 0};
                }
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            }
        }

        curl_slist_free_all(headers);
        headers = NULL; 
        //std::cout << chunk.memory << std::endl;
        return chunk.memory;
    }

    public:

    void sendSignedRequest(std::string httpMethod, std::string urlPath, std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> &parameters) {
        std::string url = baseUrl + urlPath;
        std::string postQuery = "";

         if (!parameters.empty()) {
            if (httpMethod == "POST")
            postQuery = JSON_QUERY(parameters);
            else if (httpMethod == "GET")
            url += '?' + URL_QUERY(parameters);
        }

        response = sendPrivateHTTPRequest(url, httpMethod, postQuery);
        parseJson();
    }
};

